# Would a concrete grinder remove a pebble overlay from the concrete base?

Tags: concrete

I started using a power washer in unison with a pole with a heavy metal edge on it. It's going tremendously slow. My question, if I rent a concrete grinder from Home Depot, would that remove this top layer of aggregate?

[image: pebble stone aggregate overlay]

Answer (score 1):

I have not removed a overlay but I have put a few down. If the epoxy was dry in that area it might come up easy with a pressure sprayer but a section that has plenty of epoxy will be a bugger to grind. A commercial tile chipper is like a heavy pole blade that cycles back and forth and will probably do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

What about an air powered scraper like this one:

https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200589333_200589333

We used this in the carpet business to get glued carpet off of concrete slabs.

Answer (score 0):

In my area, Home Depot rents floor buffers as concrete grinders, with a different bottom blade that looks like a giant blow-up of the circular ring blades used in electric razors.

You should NEVER, EVER rent one of those things. And certainly not for this purpose. They are actively, maliciously, homicidal. A friend and I rented one for the purpose of adhesive removal and we consider ourselves lucky to have escaped with our lives.

Instead, as someone else suggested, try renting a device that pushes/pulls a [scraper](https://www.lewiscontractorsales.com/general-fcs16-power-floor-scraper-tile-stripper.html?msclkid=d7a4cf137ae4182e4cc390ffe3c2cfca). Or a true [concrete grinder](https://www.lewiscontractorsales.com/general-sg12e-single-head-concrete-floor-grinder.html?msclkid=48943be03f521c8af772640ca62a9136), which looks like a horizontal grinding wheel attached to the front of a long-ish cart body. Or if you don't mind some heavy scarring to the concrete, you might consider a ["concrete planer/scarifier"](https://www.unitedrentals.com/marketplace/equipment/concrete-masonry/concrete-grinders-planers/scarifier-small#/). These tools you'll typically find at a tool rental place (like Sunbelt Tools, United Rentals, or Taylor Rental if they're still in business near you) more than a box store.

Also, be aware that some of these tools will be gasoline powered. Don't be afraid of that, even indoors. Just isolate the area, open windows for air flow, and get going. You'll be done in a few hours.